# What Rails-ActiveRecord association to use for this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

**Let's say I have a computer model.**

This computer has 2 characteristics:

- a name.
- a price.

How would these characteristics be associated with the Computer Model? 
 (Ex: belongs_to, has_one,yadda yadda)

Comment: plain attributes are just db columns, no need for associations. or clarify your question

Comment: you don't need associations as long as `name` and `price` are simple attributes like string or integer. associations required when you have separate models, like `Price` model and want to link them together

Answer (score 0):

I would setup the Computer model like this:

```
> bundle exec rails g model computer name:string price:integer

# app/models/computer.rb
class Computer < ApplicationRecord
end

# db/migrate/20160807225007_create_computers.rb 
class CreateComputers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :computers do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :price

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

No need for associations if both attributes are primitive types.

Answer (score -1):

if your name and price are a model than to do the association between them with the computer do like
computer model

has_many :name
has_many :price

has many and belongs to association depends upon how you want to make your associations with them

for example if you want to have different name of your computer model than has_many :name and if you want that your computer model should be of a name model than do
belongs_to :name

check this link for further details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I cannot understand ROR Guides. I understand you though.  Thanks!